# Editing style sheet doesn't work in cherry framework wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, frameworks

I use a cherry framework wordpress theme 46544 http://construccionscabrera.loading.net .When i am logged in as a administrator, my wordpress theme works very well.But when i visited the site on another browser my all editing style sheet becomes as before.I see my style sheet works when i am logged in .But user see the site as before. I only touch style.css file and cherry option in the wordpress dashboard.

Comment: Consider clearing your cache

Comment: But user see the different.It doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Alex Thomas.It works well after clearing browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete your .cache files for .less files. Here is where mine were located:

For Cherry Framework itself:

**less/bootstrap.less.cache**

**less/style.less.cache**

Then inside my child theme (this may be different for you, but find the .cache files and delete them if you’re getting errors):

**theme root/style.less.cache**

**bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less.cache**

Without deleting these files, your site will look for the .less related files and style sheets inside the old site file structure, which obviously will not work